# Vue.js 2 data not displayed in the template

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I'm using vue.js 2 / vue-cli with axios. I'm facing a problem with the display of my posts (in the wall). I've made my axios request, have gotten my data (in the console), I've written my template and ... nothing was displayed ... I really appreciate your help

my template :

```
<template>
  <v-layout column>
    <v-flex xs4>
      <panel title="The Wall">
        <p v-for="post in posts" :key="post.index">{{ post.title }} - {{ post.content }}</p>
      </panel>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

my script :

```
<script>
import Panel from '../components/Panel'
import PostService from "../services/PostService.js";

export default {
  components: {
    Panel
  },
  data() {
    return {
     posts: null
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
      this.posts = (await PostService.getAllPosts()).data;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @ziouzuw15 Make sure your API is returning data. You can check there is no error with other things - https://jsfiddle.net/hareshhanat_27/9bje87gn/6/

Answer (score 0):

Add a data property called cidItem for example and bind it to your props as follows

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container" :cid="cidItem">

    <Images :cid="cidItem" />

    <Video :cid="cidItem"  />

    <TextType :cid="cidItem"  />

    <Card :cid="cidItem"  />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios';
  import Images from "./components/Images";
  import Video from "./components/Video";
  import TextType from "./components/TextType";
  import Card from "./components/Card";

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    props: ["cid"],
    components: {
      Images,
      Video,
      TextType,
      Card
    },
    mounted() {
      axios({method: "GET", "url": this.contentDeliveryUrl}).then(result => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          this.content = amp.inlineContent(result.data)[0];
          console.log(this.content)
        }, error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
    data() {
      return {
        contentDeliveryUrl: 'https://c1.adis.ws/cms/content/query?fullBodyObject=true&query=%7B%22sys.iri%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fcontent.cms.amplience.com%2F${this.cid}%22%7D&scope=tree&store=testing',
        content: [],
        cidItem:'7e4301de-9c6e-4fab-9e68-3031b94d662d'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Since your component have the same structure i recommend to use [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html), create a file named myMixins.js and add the following code inside it :

```
const myMixins = {
 props:['cid'],
  mounted() {
    axios({
      method: "GET",
      "url": this.contentDeliveryUrl
    }).then(result => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      this.content = amp.inlineContent(result.data)[0];
      console.log(this.content)
    }, error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      contentDeliveryUrl: 'https://c1.adis.ws/cms/content/query?fullBodyObject=true&query=%7B%22sys.iri%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fcontent.cms.amplience.com%2F${this.cid}%22%7D&scope=tree&store=testing',
      content: []
    }
  }
}

export default mixins;
```

and inside each component add this :

```
import myMixins from './myMixins'
    export default{
          ....
         mixins: [myMixin]
      }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Nader but your answer seems very complicated to me. Actually I managed to retrieve the data I need why should I use components for them ?